# "Unable to load DLL 'libwkhtmltox' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)"

Tags: .net-7.0

Used  DinkToPdf for HTML To PDF.

Error is coming when  execute this line :
**return _converter.Convert(doc);**

tried to load **libwkhtmltox.dll**   and
When add reference of **libwkhtmltox ** then showing  this error .
**The reference is invalid or unsupported.**

=> I am using using .net7 ,Visual studio 2022